# pentaho: error (stderr) =256m""=="" was unexpected at this time. while calling kitchen command (dos command using shell script job entry) from job

Tags: shell, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I am getting following error while executing shell script in job (execute job inside script on windows platform)

> Blockquote 2015/05/20 12:24:56 - Shell - ERROR (version 5.2.0.0, build 1 from 2014-09-30_19-48-28 by buildguy) : (stderr) =256m""=="" was unexpected at this time.

Please find link for job j_test.kjb 
[https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hf2yl09qo5x0f1/j_test.kjb?dl=0][1]

i need to work on this, any hints will be appreciated

Comment: Unable to view the attachement?

Comment: i have added link, any inputs ... ?

Comment: Is this problem solved? I am facing this same issue